# init function invocation of drivers compiled into kernel

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In Linux if device drivers are built as loadable kernel modules, then upon inserting the device driver kernel module, the kernel calls the init function of the device driver as pointed out by `module_init()` macro.

How does this work for device drivers that are statically compiled into the kernel ? How is their init function called ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *init* routine of a built-in driver can still use the `module_init()` macro to declare that entry point.  Or the driver can use `device_initcall()` when the driver would never be compiled as a loadable module.  Or to move its initialization very early in the boot sequence, the driver could use `subsys_initcall()`.

In `include/linux/init.h` the sequence for invoking these *init* routines is described as:

```
/* initcalls are now grouped by functionality into separate 
 * subsections. Ordering inside the subsections is determined
 * by link order. 
 * For backwards compatibility, initcall() puts the call in 
 * the device init subsection.
 *
 * The `id' arg to __define_initcall() is needed so that multiple initcalls
 * can point at the same handler without causing duplicate-symbol build errors.
 */
```

I assume that these *subsections* for device drivers correspond to the subdirectories within the `drivers` directory of the Linux kernel source tree, and that the *link order* is recorded in the *built-in.o* file of each subdirectory in `drivers`. So during kernel boot the *init* routine of each built-in driver is eventually executed by `do_initcalls()` in `init/main.c`.

The *init* routine of the device driver is responsible for probing the system to verify that the HW device actually exists.  The driver should not allocate any resources or register any devices when the probe fails.

**UPDATE**:
Passing the option "initcall_debug" on the kernel command line will cause timing information to be printed to the console for each initcall. initcalls are used to initialize statically linked kernel drivers and subsystems and contribute a significant amount of time to the Linux boot process. The output looks like:

```
calling  tty_class_init+0x0/0x44 @ 1
initcall tty_class_init+0x0/0x44 returned 0 after 9765 usecs
calling  spi_init+0x0/0x90 @ 1
initcall spi_init+0x0/0x90 returned 0 after 9765 usecs
```

Reference: http://elinux.org/Initcall_Debug

Comment: suppose I want to use device_initcall for a driver, I have a question. in which section of boardfile you need to make a call to this driver.

Comment: By *"boardfile"*, I assume you are referring to arch or mach or board initialization code that typically is called very early in the boot process.  `do_initcalls()` in `init/main.c` usually happens after most of that HW initialization.  Kernel code is rarely structured to call into a driver, unless it's an `ops` function or other module-interface entry-point.  What kind of "call" are you really asking about?

Comment: Yes you got wrt board file. and it is very clear about when do_initcalls will get called. `What kind of "call" are you really asking about?` For this I would like to put the question in this way: Suppose if I have 3 kinds of devices of type switch_dev(their state need to be exported to user space). Here, device one calls device_initcall(supplied with routine that makes the object switch_dev->kobj available to other 2 devices). other two devices use normal module_init. My interest would be to move device_initcall routine to board file and use module_init for all 3. how to do that?

Comment: @zair - You probably should start a new question, and provide details and the requirements.  In general, you should not move device initialization stuff into the board file.  That could be poor code structure, since you don't want non-essential code to affect early kernel startup.

Answer (score 2):

As specified by the comments in kernel init.h

> "module_init() will either be called during do_initcalls() (if builtin) or at module
> insertion time (if a module)."

If you look into init.h then you will see

> ## define module_init(x)    __initcall(x);

And if you closely observe then

> ## define __initcall(fn) device_initcall(fn)

And

> ## define device_initcall(fn)       __define_initcall("6",fn,6)

So basically the module init leads to initcall (**NOTE: only for statically compiled modules**) at the time of boot only.