# View linux kernel drivers built into the kernel, and how do they get binded/mounted/started

Tags: embedded-linux

I'm having a bit of a hard time fully understanding how the kernel starts in linux. I'm a wince developer and our company decided to run with linux instead now.

We outsourced all of the board bringup and the package I recieved is quit a bit different for the prototype board we have compared to the nitrogen6x we have been using.

Before i start listing the differences for the distro we created, the kernels are identical. The distro we have been using is a busybox system. The one we recieved from the vendor is sysvinit. I removed mdev from busybox and we are only using udev.

when I use the kernel on our busybox build the touch screen drivers breaks, or doesn' run, or does something totally magical. I'm not quit sure... there is a /dev/input/event0 device which when run on the sysvinit side is a touch device.. Is the kernel not the mechanism that binds the built-in drivers to a device node? I thought udev was for more dynamic events in the system.

On the other hand I can't really tell whats been loaded on my device. Is there a way to list running drivers that were built into the kernel? my touch pad is up? This is a fairly simple process of looking at the registry on wince to see which devices were loaded.

I guess what I'm really trying to discover, isn't so much how to add a driver to the kernel, its how the whole thing gets is plumbed together. I've found plenty of documents on createing kernel modules, but i haven't found a good resource on how to pull everything together from scratch so you can actually use said modules. Going back to the example of the touchscreen driver, its built into the kernel, how does that get plugged into /dev/input/event0??

I'm kind of having a difficult time finding good resources mostly because searching google for varations of linux/drivers/device nodes/ piles in tons of random crap from everywhere.

Comment: Try `initcall_debug` on the kernel command line.  A little more info [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865054/init-function-invocation-of-drivers-compiled-into-kernel/12869195#12869195)  The other resource to use is the **system log**, retrievable using the **dmesg** command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want to use now is [evtest](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/evtest/). It will allow you to know what are the input devices that are present and ready to use on your system.

To get more information on the input subsystem and more generic information on how the kernel is working, I can direct you to our [training materials](http://free-electrons.com/training/kernel/). The materials are free to download, use and redistribute.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is, there is no single, easy place to look to discover what drivers have been loaded by the kernel if they are compiled in.  Of course, lsmod will display any drivers that were dynamically loaded after kernel boot.

The kernel does not create device nodes.  That is, to quote your question, the kernel does not "bind" the driver to the device node. The association between kernel driver and device node is contained in the major and minor numbers registered when the driver is initialized.  You can have a device node on your file system for which there is no corresponding driver (common especially in older devices where device nodes were statically created on the file system) and you can also have a driver installed for which there is no device node.

Modern Linux distros have dynamically created device nodes created on a mount point called /dev and this is usually a tmpfs file system, meaning it is volatile - it gets destroyed on every boot and recreated dynamically on each new boot.

udev is the magic that creates most device nodes based on events that it receives from the kernel when a new device is discovered (this can be after boot on device plugin, like a USB disk) or on startup when udev reads the queued events and acts on them.  As you noted, busybox has a limited udev implementation called mdev.

Study udev and you will get a much better understanding of the process.  Hope this helps a little.

Comment: It does help, i think the embedded distro we are using has the new method and creates the /dev folder on start.  I’m not getting all the input devices I need though. I’m missing the keypad driver I think in the device nodes list. 
So I’ll start looking into udev, that’s what we’ll be using even if we choose to switch back to busy box.

Comment: I have another quick question, are there any tutorials/platforms deisnged around walking one through getting a driver created and plummed in with udev?

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter07/udev.html
http://www.linux.com/news/hardware/peripherals/180950-udev

Reading is fun and all but I still don't understand why my touch screen doesnt get mounted in the /dev/input/event0 when using udev+busybox vs udev+sysvinit,

Comment: The best tutorial for udev is Chapter 19 of Embedded Linux Primer (http://www.amazon.com/Embedded-Linux-Primer-Practical-Real-World/dp/0137017839) by challinan. It specifically includes "Using udev with busybox".

Comment: Any other good books, someone mentioned that most of the examples are a little too simple to apply to fixing actual systems. Which is ok since I plan on getting this and hopefully some better resources to read over the holidays.