# driver not working when built as built in driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I wrote a basic character driver for beagle-bone which prints two message in 1 second interval via a workqueue and a tasklet using printk.

At first i build it as module driver, generated .ko file, load it using insmod command and the print is coming when viewed via dmesg.

Then i built as inbuilt driver and load the uImage and after bootup i checked the dmesg prints. But there is no prints.

In the .config file

```
 CONFIG_MY_DRIVER=y
```

So its taken as built in driver i think.

How can i confirm whether its actually built in the final image. No error was reported while building.

Is there any additional steps to be done for loading the build in driver.

Please pardon me if i went wrong on any basics. I am really new to linux.

Comment: If you're positive that the driver is compiled and linked into the kernel, then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865054/init-function-invocation-of-drivers-compiled-into-kernel/12869195#12869195) on how to use "initcall_debug" to check if your driver's init routine is getting invoked.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you added it probably somewhere to Kconfig file:
"CONFIG_MY_DRIVER=y"

but, Have you added it to Makefile? It works like that, then kernel during a building an Image, takes all of this directives "CONFIG_*" and use it to build particular source files from Makefile.

Example:

```
cat fs/ext2/Makefile
ext2-$(CONFIG_EXT2_FS_SECURITY)  += xattr_security.o

cat fs/ext2/Kconfig
config EXT2_FS_SECURITY
    bool "Ext2 Security Labels"
    depends on EXT2_FS_XATTR
```

so in this example above if your source file is xattr_security.c then you should get xattr_security.o file in fs/ext2 dir, when this is build. You should also see it if your file is build, during a compilation process.

Comment: I have done that modification in the make file too... But still its not working....

Comment: Could you show me all your configs? Maybe you don't just include it in ahother Makefile. is .o file created?

Comment: thanks for your helping mind. i have just put a kernel print in the init function and that print is coming which shows the device is getting registered. I will check some more with some kernel prints and will update soon