# What decides the order of drivers initialization in the Linux kernel and can I change it?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, boot

I need to modify the order of which device drivers are initialized in the Linux kernel in a way to allow the most important driver be initialized first.

It would help immensely if someone can describe where these drivers are initialized and how the order of initialization is decided.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using a subjective description such as *"the most important"*, state the requirement(s) that need to be satisfied.  Otherwise the answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865054/init-function-invocation-of-drivers-compiled-into-kernel/12869195#12869195 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541290/what-is-the-difference-between-module-init-and-subsys-initcall-while-initializin/15542788#15542788

Comment: @sawdust, your answers a bit outdated. They do not cover *-EPROBE_DEFER*. Otherwise they are quite good.