# How to use uart pin on SAMA5D2

Tags: embedded-linux, uart

I am working on SAMA5D2 and I am curently trying to use gpio UART pin, but the problem is I can't find a way to enable the uart function.

When I plugg my device in and run dmesg |grep tty , the device is not detected. No matter what I do. I "echo" the right pin but that does not seems to be enough.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Anne,

Comment: *"I can't find a way to enable the uart function."* -- Typically all non-essential peripheral devices of an SoC are disabled in the generic Device Tree **.dtsi** file for that SoC.  That is, all of the peripherals of the SoC should have nodes to establish a basic configuration (in sama5d2.dtsi), but non-essential devices will have `status = "disabled";`.  If you want to enable a peripheral, you first have to check for pin confilcts.  The peripheral can then be enabled by creating an "overlay" node in the top-level .dts file for the board.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609713/the-order-in-which-the-device-tree-text-file-is-written-does-it-matter for some basic concepts on Device Tree.  For a tutorial see https://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies.pdf