# Linux device tree module instance creation order swapped

Tags: embedded-linux, device-tree

For an embedded platform 3 gpio peripherals are defined in the device tree. 
gpio0 at the lowest address and gpio2 at the highest address. The definition in the device tree starts with gpio0.

After the system boot the gpio peripherals in sysfs are not as one would expect. gpio0 and gpio2 are swapped, which also results in incorrect gpio numbers.

Is it normal that the order of peripheral instances do not match the order in the device tree ?

How / where is the order determined ?

Thanks in advance fore any help.

Comment: Are you sure that the device tree in being applied? Check at /proc, there is a path where you can inspect the device tree there, check for the presence of the gpio that you quoted.

Comment: I am complelely sure the device tree is being used. I am also not using devicetree fragments.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609713/the-order-in-which-the-device-tree-text-file-is-written-does-it-matter

_The device nodes attached to a particular bus (e.g. apbh@80000000) could be ordered numerically by device address or alphabetically by device name. This ordering of nodes (within a bus) is not significant._

What is the platform?

Comment: You may also want to read _Interaction with the GPIO subsystem_ at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/pinctrl.txt

Comment: I would have expected ordering by device name or address, but this is what not seem to happen. sysfs exposes The platfom is  CycloneV SOC.