# Devicetree - how are "ranges" mmapped to device nodes?

Tags: device-tree

Let's say we have this example devicetree:

[image]

I just want to know what mechanism `ranges` uses so that it gets properly mapped to the device nodes (`ethernet@0,0`, `i2c@1,0`, `flash@2,0`).

Does it use:

- *"child's domain address"* (red) or
- *"order of appearance"* (violet)

to properly figure out mapping?

Comment: *"Does it use: ... to properly figure out mapping?"* -- Neither. The ordering of DT nodes is  not significant and typically for esthetics, so *"order of appearance"* can be immediately ruled out.  Looks like the *"mechanism"* could be the first value of `reg` property of each node is a memory index.  BTW the actual mapping of a device's  I/O memory is typically performed by each device driver.  The omission of a valid base address and length in the `reg` properties is unusual.

Comment: At least I know that the order does not matter. `range` is a 3-tuple consisting of (a) address from the child node's perspective, (b) address from the parent node's perspective and (c) size of that segment of addresses. So I have two ideas... Consider the range `0 0 0x10100000 0x100000` - it's address from the child node's perspective is `0 0`. It could be mapped to **A:** Child node's name `ethernet@0,0` (note the `@0,0`). But unlikely as I read somewhere that `@0,0` part is not used at all. Is this true? **B:** It is possible that the initial part of `reg = <0 0 0x100>` i.e. `0 0` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it use:
> ...
> to properly figure out mapping?

The ordering of DT nodes is not significant and typically done for esthetics, so *"order of appearance"* can be immediately ruled out.  See [The order in which the device-tree text file is written, does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609713/the-order-in-which-the-device-tree-text-file-is-written-does-it-matter)

The `range` property is supposed to be a 3-tuple of <child-bus-address>, <parent-bus-address>, and <length> values.
However the `#address-cells` property (of external-bus) specifies that the (external bus) <address> value will consist of *two* <u32> values.  This "double-length" is applied only to <child-bus-address>, while <parent-bus-address> is a single <u32> value per the `#address-cells` property of the parent node.
The `#size-cells` property specifies that the <length> value will consist of a single <u32> value.
Therefore the `rangle` property will apparently in your example consist of "triplets" composed of 4 values, the first two for <child-bus-address>, the next for <parent-bus-address>,  and the last for <length>.

The `reg` property is supposed to be a pairs of <address> and <length> values.
Since the external-bus `#address-cells` property specifies (and/or the default value is 2 anyway) that the <address> value will consist of *two* <u32> values , and the `#size-cells` property specifies that the <length> value will consist of a single <u32> value, the `reg` property will in your example consist of a "pair" composed of 3 values, the first two for <address> and the last for <length>.

---

Note that the DT Specification requires that the <address> in the `reg` property must match the "@<unit-address>" in the node name.  The additional ",0" in the <unit-address> is what what you guessed, the later half of the <address> in each `reg`.

---

So the answer to your question would be the <child-bus-address>, which is related to the chip select value.
However, rather than cite the <unit-address> in the node name, the salient linkage *"mechanism"* in the device node is the <address> in the `reg` property.