# Device Tree - Overlap in memory

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, device-tree

One of the device tree specification file I came across has the following entry. If I understand it right, it has two memory regions starting at the address `40000000` as the node name shown as `memory@40000000`. The two ranges are  `0x00 to 0x40000000` and `0x00 to 0x20000000`. Aren't they overlapping? Why the node name says memory starts at `0x40000000` when the 'reg' entry contains `0x00`

What is the correct interpretation of this memory node? (I went through the device tree specification, but I could not clearly understand this aspect)

```dts
memory@40000000 {
    reg = <0x00 0x40000000 0x00 0x20000000>;
    device_type = "memory";
};
```

Comment: "*If I understand it right, it has two memory regions ...*" -- Most likely a faulty assumption on your part. Only if the parent bus node specifies `#address-cells = <1>;`  could your guess be reasonable. The `reg` property is supposed to be pairs of <address> and <length> values, but each of those values could be *two* <u32> values. IOW the parent bus probably specifies `#address-cells = <2>;` and `#size-cells = <2>;`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808359/devicetree-how-are-ranges-mmapped-to-device-nodes/70856909#70856909

Comment: If the parent node specified `#address-cells = <2>;` and `#size-cells = <2>;`, That reg entry would specify a single range with 64-bit address 0x0000000040000000 and 64-bit size 0x0000000020000000. (Cells are 32 bits wide in big-endian byte order. Multi-cell values are in big-endian cell order.)