# understanding device tree reg property

Tags: device-tree

I was reading "Power.org™ Standard for Embedded Power Architecture™ Platform Requirements (ePAPR)". In the book, it says that;

```
Suppose a device within a system-on-a-chip had two blocks of registers—a 32-byte block at offset 0x3000 in the SOC and a 256-byte block at offset 0xFE00. The reg property would be encoded as follows
(assuming #address-cells and #size-cells values of 1):

reg = <0x3000 0x20 0xFE00 0x100>;
```

ı think that the address-cells and size-cells have to be 2. Can someone explain why and how it equals to 1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Devicetree - how are "ranges" mmapped to device nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808359/devicetree-how-are-ranges-mmapped-to-device-nodes)