# Understanding register field in dts files

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I'm trying to understand the address field in a dts file, could anyone help me understand what this means? why are 8 values in this?

```
smmu-pmu@13aa2000 {
            compatible = "arm,smmu-v3-pmcg";
            reg = <0x00 0x13aa2000 0x00 0x1000 0x00 0x13ab2000 0x00 0x1000>;
            mtk,smmu = <0x10a>;
            phandle = <0x2bf>;
        };
```

I'm guessing 0x13aa2000 is the starting address and it ends at 0x13ab2000, is that correct?

Comment: That is not a "*dts file*"; it's just one Device Tree node out of context. The Device Tree cannot be understood merely by reviewing it. The answer is in the Device Tree specification document. E.G. to properly understand the values in the `reg` property, you need to know the values of the `#address-cells` and `#size-cells` properties of the parent node. BTW odds are that your guess is incorrect, simply because it doesn't account for every value.

Comment: The parent node has the following

 soc {
  compatible = "simple-bus";
  #address-cells = <0x02>;
  #size-cells = <0x02>;

Comment: You have 4 and not 8, and they are simply as $addr1, $size1, $addr2, $size2. Isn't it obvious? :-) (Hint the values are in BE64 in 32-bit stances)

Comment: You have two regions. Region[0] is at address 0x0000000013aa2000 with length 0x0000000000001000. Region[1] is at address 0x0000000013ab2000 with length 0x0000000000001000.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Devicetree - how are "ranges" mmapped to device nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808359/devicetree-how-are-ranges-mmapped-to-device-nodes)